# What's a good umbrella term for different types of "ventures" in a single building?

Tags: single-word-requests

If there's a city building and it consists of:

- A bar in basement
- Small general store on ground floor
- 10 floors or apartments

Is there a good umbrella term in English to describe them? Context:

> This building consists of 3 different ... - bar, general store and 30 apartments.

Venture is the only thing that pops into my mind but it doesn't sound right (not native speaker).

Comment: Did you mean _venues_? Ventures has nothing to do with buildings.

Comment: As always, my preferred response to requests for single words is to avoid them entirely.  What's wrong with *The building (contains/includes/houses/comprises) a bar, a general store and thirty apartments.*?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark especially if they are going to be detailed anyway.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I agree, that would be preferable in most contexts but I do have a hard requirement to describe it with one, maximum few words.

Comment: You could call it a "multi-use" or "multipurpose" building (housing a range of commercial and private tenants).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Buildings such as these are known as *mixed-use* buildings, and the things happening in them are called *uses*.

Your building has three uses: entertainment (bar), retail (store), and residential (apartments).

Here are some examples:

> A mixed-use building is a type of property that blends residential,
> commercial, industrial, entertainment and even industrial uses into
> one space.
>  <sub>[Mansion Global — *Mixed-Use
> Building*](https://www.mansionglobal.com/library/mixed-use-building)</sub>

> A mixed-use building aims to combine three or more uses into one
> structure such as residential, hotel, retail, parking, transportation,
> cultural, and entertainment.
>  <sub>[TK Elevator — *Mixed-use
> buildings: make the most of your
> building*](https://blog.tkelevator.com/mixed-use-buildings-for-diversified-sustainable-sites/)</sub>

> Falling into a broader category of mixed-use developments, a vertical
> mixed-use building may house any combination of businesses. Typically,
> however, public uses such as restaurants, coffee shops, government
> offices, and even transit facilities congregate on the lower floors,
> while private uses the likes of condo units or hotel rooms are located
> higher up.
>  <sub>[Casey — *What is a Mixed-Use
> Building?*](https://www.caseydev.com/what-is-a-mixed-use-building/)</sub>

Answer (score 8):

This occurs often in New York. For example, a building whose landlord rents out units might have storefront businesses on the ground floor and residential units on upper floors. We often simply call all of them the building's "tenants":

> This building has 32 different tenants: a bar, a general store, and 30 apartments.

From [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/tenant):

> someone who rents an apartment, house, office, piece of land, etc. from the person who owns it
> *There are six commercial tenants in the building.*

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question: the OP is seeking a word for something like the **types** of spaces that the tenants may occupy. The sentence that exemplifies the intended use of the term says that there are **3** of what the term stands for, not 32.

Comment: @jsw29 I see what you mean and was, in fact, confused by OP's use of "3" instead of "32". (I thought it was a typo.) The reason I thought he or she wanted an umbrella term for the units themselves was that the title says *different "ventures"*, not *different types of "ventures"*. Until that changes, I'll leave this answer. (OP: Please edit either the title or the question to make your meaning clear.)

Comment: Yes, *venture* is not the most illuminating term here, but I suspect that what the OP has in mind is that the 30 apartments are all managed together, in the same way, and so managing them counts as one business; they are all together one business venture when looked at from the perspective of the entrepreneur who manages them.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, that might have been the intention, but I still don't think it's clear. After all, in that case I'd think a landlord would divide the building into either 32 individual units or 2 classes of units (commerical and residential), not 3.